# printing a PHP string and parsing it as a JSON in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a json_string in my database.
I echo and parse it to an object in javascript

I do

```
$.parseJSON('<?php echo $json_string;?>');
```

I get a json parse error.
What should I be doing?

This is my json_String

```
{"patches":[[{"diffs":[[1,"\u000a\u000a printhellon() {\u000a\u000a\u000a}d\u000a\u000a\u000a"]],"start1":0,"start2":0,"length1":0,"length2":26}],[{"diffs":[[0,") {\u000a\u000a\u000a}d"],[1,"s"],[0,"\u000a\u000a\u000a"]],"start1":15,"start2":15,"length1":11,"length2":12}],[{"diffs":[[0," {\u000a\u000a\u000a}ds"],[1,"d"],[0,"\u000a\u000a\u000a"]],"start1":16,"start2":16,"length1":11,"length2":12}]],"times":[1314489779299,1314489779408,1314489779581]}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why call `.parseJSON` all?  Why not just assign the object directly to a variable, since you are outputting directly in the same script anyway?

Comment: @Brad thank you that works :-) . but then I am confused myself, why would I use $.parseJSon then?

Comment: @SAnandNarayan: you'd use `parseJSON` when you for example get it from the server with AJAX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think JSON parsers don't like line breaks in strings for some reason. Parsing worked for me after removing the \u000a characters.

Edit: just like Brad said, it would be better to include the code directly as an object. Parsing JSON is usually more useful for data obtained using Ajax or something.

Answer (score -3):

From your example, it appears like you're trying to insert PHP code into your javascript. You can't use PHP like that. PHP is server side, while Javascript runs in the browser after the page has been downloaded.

If you must get data from PHP to your javascript, you need to use AJAX. It's actually really easy with JQuery. Check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You can use PHP to generate anything you want, including JavaScript.